# Accessing multi dimensional ArrayList values

Tags: java, arraylist

I am getting 3 columns for each row from mysql table by using ResultSet. I am not sure about the number of rows I will get by using query. To store those rows I am using `ArrayList` as given code below:

```
while (rs.next()) 
{
    String[] row = new String[numcols];
    for (int i = 0; i < numcols; i++) 
    {
        row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);                                  
    }  
    rowsList.add(row);                     
}
rs.close();
```

When I debugged the code I found columns values are present in the `ArrayList`. Now I am unable to access the columns values because `rowsList.get(index)` will return only value at specific index but I have further 3 more values at that index how to access those values.

Comment: please follow my answer. Good luck using list and class rather than using Array in such a complex way

Comment: try-- `String colValue=rowsList.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex];`

Comment: why don't you use a dto instead get the rows then add the column values to the dto object add the object to the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.get()` in your case will return a `String` array: `String[]`. You can access the elements of an array by using the `[]` index operators:

```
String[] row = rowList.get(0);
for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
    System.out.println(row[i]);

// Or you can use the enhanced for to loop through the array:
for (String s : row)
    System.out.println(s);
```

If you want to process all rows:

```
for (String[] row : rowList) {
    // Process row
    for (String s : row) {
        // Do something with the string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you to learn about [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

And the second would be to **create a class** that holds everything that comes from your query.

And finally **save each object** of the class to the array.

**Example**

Suppose you get **id**, **name** and **address** columns from your query

**Create a class**

```
public class YourClass{
int id;
String name, address;
//create getters and setters or use a constructor
//example of setter to set field id
public void setId(int id){
this.id = id;
     }
}
```

And then while retrieving the records from query, create an object of your class and set the columns as field of your class as follow:

```
YourClass anObject = new YourClass();
anObject.setId(id);// get similar columns from query
anObject.setName(name);
```

And finally add the object to the **ArrayList** as below:

```
yourArrayList.add(anObject);
```

To take care of multiple number of records you need to keep these code inside the `while` loop
And define your `List` before while loop as follow:

```
List<YourClass> yourArrayList = new ArrayList<YourClass>();
```

And I think this is the **best approach** as it uses OOP that you should begin using instead of using bare array.

Answer (score 1):

you would want to specify what object is in the list. to achieve this make your `List` to `List<String[]> rowsList = new ArrayList<String[]>();`

then use your `while` loop

```
while (rs.next()) 
{
    String[] row = new String[numcols];
    for (int i = 0; i < numcols; i++) 
    {
        row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);                                  
    }  
    rowsList.add(row);                     
}
rs.close();
```

when you access each item in the list it will always return a `String[]` which you can iterate to get the values.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< rowsList.size() ; i++){
   rowsList.get(i);//will return a String[]
}
```

**OR**

```
for(String[] rows : rowsList){
   //iterate the rows
}
```